Как сделать редактирование текста в ToDoList?
Как в ToDoList'е правильно реализовать кнопку Редактировать (она обведена красным на скриншоте)? Нужно, чтобы при нажатии можно было изменить текст.
Не совсем понимаю на уровне возможностей React'а как это сделать. Поле должно быть input'ом, чтобы его редактировать, и потом это вставить в стейт уже в обновлённом виде? Или как?


Ваш код в студию, с которым не смогли справится.

добрый день . я еще не  писал код. у меня на стадии планирования возникли вопросы как это можно реализовать. и я не понимаю каким образом может редактироваться уже написанный элемент. вот в чем вопрос

я не понимаю каким образом может редактироваться уже написанный элемент он заменяется элементом, который может редактироваться...


я не понимаю каким образом может редактироваться уже написанный элемент

Вот пример того, как можно заменять "написанный" элемент на "редактируемый"...


//
const Edit = ({set, val, ok}) => {
  const aok = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    ok(false) 
  }
  const aval = e => set(e.target.value)
  return <form onSubmit={aok}>
    <input value={val} onChange={aval} />
    <button>Ok</button>
  </form>
}
//
const View = ({set, val}) => {
  const act = _ => set(true) 
  return <div className='view'>
    <span>{val}</span>
    <button onClick={act}>Редактировать</button>
  </div>
}
//
const App = _ => {
  const [val, setVal] = React.useState('')
  const [ok, setOk] = React.useState(false)
  return <section>
    {ok ? <Edit val={val} set={setVal} ok={setOk} /> : <View val={val} set={setOk} />}
  </section>
}

const domContainer = document.querySelector('#like_button_container');
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(domContainer);
root.render(<App />);
.view,
form {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
  & span,
  & input {
    width: 200px;
  }
}
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<div id="like_button_container"></div>




спасибо! буду разбираться
